# How can I exclude file rows that are non numerical for use by XTS in R?

Tags: r, shiny, xts

I have a reactive dataframe that reads a file that updates with new data. Occasionally the data in the file will have error messages or other non numeric lines and will break the order.by XTS function.

| timestamp | siteid | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1666800000 | 144496 | 58.933 | 53.7 | 5.094 | 5.141 |
| 1666782000 | 144496 | 62.575 | 49.1 | 0.635 | 0.754 |
| 1666749600 | 144496 | 58.567 | 58.733 | 3.843 | 2.438 |
| <"html> |  |  |  |  |  |
| <"sometext> |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1666760400 | 144496 | 71.959 | 51.872 | 0.037 | 0.041 |

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ez.read = function(file, ..., skip.rows=NULL, tolower=FALSE){
    if (!is.null(skip.rows)) {
      tmp = readLines(file)
      tmp = tmp[-(skip.rows)]
      tmpFile = tempfile()
      on.exit(unlink(tmpFile))
      writeLines(tmp,tmpFile)
      file = tmpFile
    }
    result = read.csv(file, ...)
    if (tolower) names(result) = tolower(names(result))
    return(result)
  }
  
  data <- reactivePoll(1000 * 60 * 15, session,
                       checkFunc = function() { file.info("merged.csv")$mtime}, 
                       valueFunc = function() {
                         data <- ez.read("merged.csv", tolower = T)
                         data$time_stamp <- as_datetime(data$time_stamp)
                         
})  
  
  renderTable(data())

n51921_cfa <- xts(x = data()$value1, order.by = data()$date)
```

Warning: Error in xts: 'order.by' cannot contain 'NA', 'NaN', or 'Inf'

How do I ignore these rows?

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to convert the garbage text data to a numeric type will yield `NA`, then simply ignore any entries that are `NA` upon conversion...

```r
idx <- (as.integer(data$timestamp) |> is.na() == FALSE) |> which()
n51921_cfa <- xts(x = data[ idx, 'value1' ], order.by = data[ idx, 'timestamp' ])
```